# How to convert a C# list of DateTimes to local JS date?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

I've looped through a list of C# DateTime's on a view using Razor syntax and bound to a table on the view.

What I need to do before the values are bound to the table is convert to the browser's local time. The `UpdatedTime` passed in is in UTC timezone from the server.

So I need to somehow convert each `UpdatedTime` property in the `Models.Escalation` list to local before it is bound to the table.

I did try calling `@item.UpdatedTime.ToLocalTime()` but this converts to the server side local time which is UTC. *Not the browser local time.*

**Question:**

How can you convert a C# list of DateTime's to local on client side JS?

I do know how to convert a single DateTime value to local using a moment. But not sure how I can apply that to the complete Models.Escalation list:

```
var updatedTimeISO = moment.utc('@Model.UpdatedTime').toISOString();
var updatedTimeLocal = moment(updatedTimeISO);

@Model.UpdatedTime = updatedTimeLocal ;
```

The table loop that binds the C# DateTime's to a table in the Razor view:

```
               <tbody>

                    @foreach (Models.Escalation item in Model)
                    {

                        <tr>  
                            <td data-order="@item.UnixTimeStamp" class="td-limit">@item.UpdatedTime.ToString("f")</td>

                            <td class="td-limit">@item.EventName</td>

                        </tr>

                    }


                </tbody>
```

Comment: did the answer I provided solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this on the server side if you know what timezone you want to convert too.

```
 DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    try
    {
       TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
       DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
       Console.WriteLine("The date and time are {0} {1}.", 
                         cstTime, 
                         cstZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(cstTime) ?
                                 cstZone.DaylightName : cstZone.StandardName);
    }
    catch (TimeZoneNotFoundException)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("The registry does not define the Central Standard Time zone.");
    }                           
    catch (InvalidTimeZoneException)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Registry data on the Central Standard Time zone has been corrupted.");
    }
```

If you don't know the browsers timezone you could use the following jQuery and moment JS code:

```js
$(".td-limit").each(function () {
  var updatedTimeISO = moment.utc($(this).data('order')).toISOString();
  var updatedTimeLocal = moment(updatedTimeISO);
    $(this).text(updatedTimeLocal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
   <tr>  
     <td data-order="2013-05-02T21:01:26.0828604Z" class="td-limit"></td>
     <td data-order="2013-04-02T21:01:26.0828604Z" class="td-limit"></td>
     <td data-order="2013-03-02T21:01:26.0828604Z" class="td-limit"></td>
     <td data-order="2013-02-02T21:01:26.0828604Z" class="td-limit"></td>
     <td data-order="2013-01-02T21:01:26.0828604Z" class="td-limit"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I like this client side solution, will try out and see how it goes.

Comment: That is great.  If it helps you out please make sure to accept the answer.  Good luck.

Comment: On second look my full code has multiple td's that use the class "td-limit", How can I target conversion to local of only the td's containing `@item.UpdatedTime` ?

Comment: I don't think that this is a good idea. The most reliable way of dealing with datetimes is the strict use of UTC on the server side, delivering UTC to the client and then converting *there* to local time (and vice versa). Everything else is an ugly hazzle in my eyes.

Comment: I opened another question on the current issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846647/how-to-convert-each-col-by-index-in-a-table-to-local-moment

Comment: @Robert that is my aim, UTC is currently passed in from my server side, then I'm trying to convert each UpdatedTime in that table to local browser time using moment.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you in the first place. I ran into a similar issue and had a lot of problems with C#'s datetime formats in AJAX requests - until I converted each datetime that goes to the client to a simple unix timestamp before sending it back. The timestamp can then be easily converted back in JS on reception.